# InitialViewController swift - выбор при запуске приложения начального контроллера представления

Tags: swift, storyboard, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults

В проекте пользователь должен пройти несколько view  , которые связанны между собой NavigationController ,где заполнит имя , пол и тд. Потом переходит на TabBarController где продолжает  пользоваться приложением.

Никак не могу понять, как запустить вьюхи только при первом запуске приложения на девайсе , что бы после входа в это же приложение  главным был не первый Navigationcontroller a TabBarController

Пока что есть такой код в файле AppDelegate.swift
Но по какой-то причине InitialViewController  все время Navigation либо TabBar

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  let isLogin = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "Islogin")
    if isLogin {
       self.StartViewController(storybordid: "TabBarControllerid")


    }else{
       self.StartViewController(storybordid: "NavigationControllerid")

    }

    return true
}
```

И функция в классе делегата

```
   func StartViewController(storybordid:String)
{

    let storyBoard:UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let exampleVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:storybordid )

    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = exampleVC
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому  пригодится решение !

это код в методе  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
  self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    let homeController: UIViewController

    let is_authenticated = def.bool(forKey: "is_authenticated") // return false if not found or stored value

    if is_authenticated {
        // user logged in
        homeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarControllerid") as! UITabBarController // create instance of HomeController or from Storyboard

    }else {
        homeController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationControllerid") as! UINavigationController
    }
    saveLoggedState()

    window?.rootViewController = homeController // change rootViewController to HomeController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible() // show window
```

И функция в классе делегата

```
 func saveLoggedState() {

    let def = UserDefaults.standard
    def.set(true, forKey: "is_authenticated") // save true flag to UserDefaults
    def.synchronize()

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var initialViewController: UIViewController

    if UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Logined") == "true"//your condition if user is already logged in or not
    {
        // if already logged in then redirect to MainViewController

        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! UITabBarController // 'MainController' is the storyboard id of MainViewController
    }
    else
    {
        //If not logged in then show LoginViewController
        initialViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginVC") as! SignInViewController // 'LoginController' is the storyboard id of LoginViewController

    }

    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Этот код не помог, но помогла ваша идея хранить это значения. 
Я написал так, и работает все )

Comment: @GlebSeredyuk, можете опубликовать ваш ответ? Может кому то пригодится ваш код

Comment: Да, я опубликовал код ниже .